# ACBrSAT erro após atualização do SNV

Tags: delphi, erp

Utilizo o ACBrSAT em um frente de caixa, acontece que depois de atualizar o ACBrSAT pelo SVN meu projeto não compila mais, dá erro nas seguintes linhas

```
if ACBrSAT1.Modelo = mfe_Integrador_XML then
begin
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).PastaInput := 'C:\Integrador\Input\';
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).PastaOutput := 'C:\Integrador\Output\';
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).Timeout := 30;
end;
```

Ele reclama que não encontra a propriedade PastaInput / PastaOutput e Timeuot

Alguém sabe por quais propriedades foram substituidas?

Algumas outras linhas que deram erro em outras propriedades eu consegui acertar, mas essas eu não encontrei na Unit

Comment: Já resolvi o problema, estou esperando o timeout para que eu possa responder a pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Após atualizar o ABCrSAT via SVN precisei fazer duas mudanças nos meus códigos

1:

de:

```
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.Margens.Topo := 5;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.Margens.Fundo := 5;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.Margens.Esquerda := 4;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.Margens.Direita := 4;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MostrarPreview := True;  
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.PrinterName := 'EPSON TM-T20';
```

para:

```
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MargemSuperior := 5;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MargemInferior := 5;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MargemEsquerda := 4;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MargemDireita := 4;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.MostraPreview := True;
  ACBrSATExtratoFortes1.Impressora := 'EPSON TM-T20';
```

2:

Adicionar o compomente ACBrIntegrador1 que antes era utilizado pela classe:

```
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).PastaInput := 'C:\Integrador\Input\';
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).PastaOutput := 'C:\Integrador\Output\';
  TACBrSATMFe_integrador_XML(ACBrSAT1.SAT).Timeout := 30;
```

e mudar a linhas para:

```
  ACBrIntegrador1.PastaInput := 'C:\simpdv\Integrador\Input\';
  ACBrIntegrador1.PastaOutput := 'C:\simpdv\Integrador\Output\';
  ACBrIntegrador1.Timeout := 30;
```